# Two divs side-by-side without hardcoded widths

Tags: html, css

I looked at few other questions about this but could not find one exactly matching my case. Here is fiddler I'm trying:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="price">ABCDEF</div>
    <div class="text">
        Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
        Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.wrapper {
    color: white;
}

.text {
    background: red;
}

.price {
    float: right;
    background: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p1q3xy00/

[image]

I need to make red div stop at the left edge of blue div and not have any text from red div underneath blue one. I also can't specify width for blue div explicitly it should be determined by its content. Is it possible?

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support?

Comment: @Huangism: Can you elaborate what exactly I need to do?

Comment: You could try https://jsfiddle.net/p1q3xy00/8/ I don't know how this looks in other browsers. I checked on FF. I was going to move the price to the right and make the wrapper display `table` and the content `table-cell`. The only difference you see in that case is the blue bg colour will fill the entire height of the cell, ie https://jsfiddle.net/p1q3xy00/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change to this:

```
.text {
  background: red;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97nLkr9p/)

This allows it to function as a table cell therefore will not overlap any other divs

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I love SO for - simple, correct and right where I need it.